# Is assigning multiple selectors into one var an array?

Tags: jquery

Is assigning multiple elements into one variable considered an array?

```
var $myList = $("#elOne, #elTwo, #elThree, etc");
```

If not, what is it? Also, is adding the '$' to the var name just standard practice to remind developers that this is an element reference variable?

Comment: Here's the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$` is to remind developers that this variable holds reference to a jQuery object.

And Yes, `$myList` will hold all the element that your selector applied to as an array(*although it's a jquery object it just holds them like an array*)

Answer (score 1):

`$("#elOne, #elTwo, #elThree, etc")` is jquery way of combining selectors. It will return array of all matching elements.
Adding `$` is a convention to indicate that variable is holding jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

This effectively calls getElementsByTagName() under the hood. 
It returns a NodeList not an array.

Comment: How can you look "under the hood"? The most I can do is use console.log to see things...

Comment: I did not look under the hood - I just read the documentation :-) - http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/

Comment: My copy of Flanagan's Definitive Guide arrived yesterday. So I've got that going for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

The jquery object is always array-like object, regardless of what the selector looks like, or how many matches it returns. Even if no element in the document matches your selector, you will simply get an empty list, rather than `null`.

The `$` in front of the variable name doesn't make it special, it's just a convention that you can decide to follow.

Answer (score 0):

`$("#elOne, #elTwo, #elThree, etc")` is a jQuery object which is not an array, but just an array-like object.

Since it's a jQuery object, you could use all the methods defined at `jQuery.prototype`(which is the same as `jQuery.fn`).