# Removing item from array without iterating

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've looked through some documentation, but I feel like there's an easier method to remove one item from an array without using an iteration loop.

http://jsfiddle.net/G97bt/1/

Updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G97bt/6/ using `not()`

---

```
<button id="1">1</button>
<button id="2">2</button>
<button id="3">3</button>

<div id="1a">Test</div>
<div id="2a">Test</div>
<div id="3a">Test</div>

var $myList = $("#1a, #2a, #3a");

$("#1").on("click", function() {
    $myList.fadeOut(); // I want to fade DIVs #2a + #3a, not ALL
    $("#1a").fadeIn("slow");    
});
$("#2").on("click", function() {
    $myList.fadeOut(); // I want to fade DIVs #1a + #3a, not ALL
    $("#2a").fadeIn("slow");    
});
$("#3").on("click", function() {
    $myList.fadeOut(); // I want to fade DIVs #1a + #2a, not ALL    
    $("#3a").fadeIn("slow");    
});
```

---

This is how I'm *envisioning* it would function:

```
$myList.remove['#1a'].fadeOut();
```

Comment: javscript `.splice()` ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: `.filter` is your buddy

Comment: Ugh. I even read through using splice() but it didn't click. Thank you, and sorry for a silly question :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like below, by using **[.not](https://api.jquery.com/not/)** to remove elements from the set of matched elements:

```
$myList.not('#1a').fadeOut();
```

And note `$myList` is not an array but a jQuery object(even it behaves like an array).

You could also rewrite your code like below:

```
var $myList = $("#1a, #2a, #3a");

$("#1,#2,#3").on("click", function() {
    $myList.not('#'+this.id+'a').fadeOut();
    $('#'+this.id+'a').fadeIn("slow");    
});
```

**[The working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/G97bt/11/)**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22762173/is-assigning-multiple-selectors-into-one-var-an-array/22762269?noredirect=1#22762269

Comment: @Sophisticake Because `.not()` is designed to do such job. And `splice()` is a method of array, not jQuery object. `splice()` returns the removed element by position, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $("[id$=a]").hide();

  $("#"+this.id+"a").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

`$arrayName.splice(position, number of elements)`